# Selecting a maximum order number in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that records a sequence of actions with a field that records the sequence order:

```
user    data    sequence
1       foo     0
1       bar     1
1       baz     2
2       foo     0
3       bar     0
3       foo     1
```

Selecting the first item for each user is easy enough with WHERE sequence = '0' but is there a way to select the last item for each user in SQL?

The result I am after should look like this:

```
user    data    sequence
1       baz     2
2       foo     0
3       foo     1
```

I'm using MySQL if there are any implementation specific tricksters answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sql will return the record with the highest sequence value for each user:

```
select a.user, a.data, a.sequence
from table as a
    inner join (
        select user, max(sequence) as 'last'
        from table 
        group by user) as b
    on a.user = b.user and 
       a.sequence = b.last
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd have expected "inner join (select user, max(sequence) as 'last' from table group by user) as b on a.user = b.user".  Different interpretations of the question, I guess.

Comment: epheminent is technically correct (the best kind of correct).

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks. He's grouped by user and only shown the last data.

Comment: In translating the meta variables into my data I had ended up with the right result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 
       user
       ,data
       ,sequence
 from table
order
   by sequence
```

Comment: This may be the simplest yet elegant solution

Comment: That will only return one item. The question was for the max sequence of each user. Keith's answer is spot on, you need a correlated query to do this?